# Visual studio 2013 GridView Greyed out?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have noticed that my Visual Studio Tool box is missing most of the tools I need.  At this moment I am trying to add a GridView from under the Data tab but this is greyed out.  I only found this out by showing all files on my toolbox.

Comment: Is it inside a new project or an existing one? Usually the project type or framework version doesn't match when this happens.

Comment: @Filburt this is for both new projects and existing ones.